# advancedDataGrid set highlighted element programmatically

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I'd like to be able to tell my ADG to set a specific row to be highlighted and update the adg rendering to match such new value. Note: highlight != selected.
I thought perhaps setting highlightUID would do the trick, but I can't seem to get the ADG rendering to update. Would love any quick tips.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Make a custom AdvancedDataGrid with this function :

```
public function indicesToItemRenderer(
    rowIndex:int, colIndex:int):IListItemRenderer
{
    var firstItemIndex:int = verticalScrollPosition - offscreenExtraRowsTop;
    if (rowIndex < firstItemIndex ||
        rowIndex >= (firstItemIndex + listItems.length))
    {
        return null;
    }

    return listItems[rowIndex - firstItemIndex][colIndex];
}
```

2) When you want to hightlight an item, call this code :

```
youCustomADG.indicesToItemRenderer(
    idxRow, idxCol).dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER);
```